# Networking For Openstack Instances

Tags: networking, openstack, subnet, openstack-neutron

I have an OpenStack Installation Running on 2 Computer Setup (1 Controller and 1 Compute Node).

My Physical Network that I used to connect Controller and Compute nodes also provides me Internet using a Static IP (College Internet Network).

I am using 2 IPs (192.168.10.6 and 10.7) for the Controller and Compute.

What should I do to have my Instances access the Internet?

I tried putting the instances on the same subnet 192.168.10.0/24 but I'm still not able to access the internet.

How should I configure?

Comment: Is your OpenStack setup has an external network with a subnet having the `192.168.10.0/24` cidr? If so can you ping controller node's IP from your instance? I am assuming there is a virtual router and a virtual network in between your external network and instance

Comment: @kuro I'm not able ping.. that is the problem.. how do i go about getting that done